# How to DRY has_attached_file that I write in 5 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, optimization

This is my code that I write in 5 different models (same code).

```
has_attached_file :image,
    s3_region: 'ap-northeast-1',
    storage: :s3,
    s3_protocol: :https,
    s3_credentials:  "#{Rails.root}/config/amazon_s3.yml",
    url: ':s3_domain_url',
    path:  '/images/:id/:filename',
    s3_host_alias: 'https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/'
```

Is there any way to DRY it out so that I have it only in one place and use it in different models?

Comment: I would recommend moving this code into configs and initializers.

Comment: @Ilya's comment might be not quite clear. See edited answer for some advice on storing storage settings within your application (which you did not ask about, but might be interested in).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use [concenrs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html).

```
# models/concenrs/attachable.rb
module Attachable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_attached_file :image,
      s3_region: 'ap-northeast-1',
      storage: :s3,
      s3_protocol: :https,
      s3_credentials:  "#{Rails.root}/config/amazon_s3.yml",
      url: ':s3_domain_url',
      path:  '/images/:id/:filename',
      s3_host_alias: 'https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/'
  end
end
```

In model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include Attachable
end
```

P.S. What Ilya meant by his chary comment is that while keeping S3 storage settings in the model is a working solution, you'd be better of putting these into config file. For some examples, see [official Paperclip-with-Amazon-S3 guide](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Paperclip-with-Amazon-S3) (there are also links to other articles and docs on [`Paperclip::Storage::S3`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3) class).

An option would be:

```
# config/secrets.yml
defaults: &defaults
  amazon:
    s3_bucket_name: 's3_bucket_name'
    aws_access_key_id: 'access_key_id'
    aws_secret_access_key: 'aws_secret_access_key'
    aws_region: 'aws_region'

# config/environments/production.rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: Rails.application.secrets.amazon['s3_bucket_name'],
    access_key_id: Rails.application.secrets.amazon['aws_access_key_id'],
    secret_access_key: Rails.application.secrets.amazon['aws_secret_access_key'],
    s3_region: Rails.application.secrets.amazon['aws_regio'],
  }
}
```